# Java regex- check for containing words

Tags: java, regex

I have a statement (st1):

```
cat#n#1
```

and another statement(st2) that I would like check if it 'contains'  "cat" and "n#1".

```
dog, rabbit, cat#n#1
```

I tried to do a pattern check by doing:

```
if(Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(st1), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(st2).find())
```

And it works in those cases when cat#n#1. But if the sentence is dog, fish, cat#n#1 then it doesn't work. I guess it's because the sentence is not exactly the same as st1.

I've done a lot of regex reading and experimenting with String.contains(), String.matches(), String.equals() and the Pattern method, but I can't get it to work as I want.

For example a

```
if(st2.toLowerCase().contains("cat") && st2.toLowerCase().contains("n#1"))
```

returns true for more than the exactly 1 correct answer. These wrong answers can be for example:

```
dog, fish, bird, eagle, cat, thing#n#4
```

So I'm hoping for a little clarification here, thanks :)

Edit: 
I need to add specifics about when the checks are done, at the start or at the end. So I need to find that solution and try again, thanks :)

Comment: `st2.toLowerCase().contains(n#1)` should be `st2.toLowerCase().contains("n#1")`

Comment: `st2.toLowerCase().contains("cat") && st2.toLowerCase().contains("n#1")` if it is not just a typo error on your part. This should work fine

Comment: I thought so too. But that if-statement is true in more than one case, which shouldn't be the case.
 if((st2.matches("(?i).*("cat").*")) && st2.matches("(?i).*("n#1").*"))  also give me more than 1 match. I normally have variables inside this if-statement, thats why there is some doubled up stuff..

Comment: Not sure how the last example with n#4 could possibly match n#1 ??

Comment: I researched it, and my program runs a loop to check for different words that are based on input from user. So the variables I'm checking for can contain words like "as", "cat", "dog", "walk", "a". Specifically, the "a" word is causing me trouble, because it's used inside a word or to define if it's an adjective and stuff.. So I need to get a better check in place! :) One that checks first the start of the word (before the "#") and a check that checks the end!

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you trying to do, the code you described above seem to work fine

Comment: Yes it did :) The problem was the variables I looped, they contained for example "a#o", "as#o", "for#ND" etc. Now I first check if the variables contains #0 or #ND, if they do, I skip that variable, and get the next one. Thats because these variables gave me false positives. Now I'm using two contain statements, and it works fine :) Thanks!